# limit notation syntax validity

Tags: limits, notation

If you know $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$$, is it valid syntax to write $$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = -\infty$$?

Comment: Yes. In fact, is very useful notation.

Comment: I disagree with the opinions expressed so far, the notation $\lim \limits_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = -\infty$ could rightfully be interpreted as $\lim \limits_{x \to  \infty} f(x) = -\infty\lor \lim \limits_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = -\infty$. As for the validity, I don't know if it is used commonly used or not, but if it isn't, you're free to give it a meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me it's fine, althought if you want to phrase it differently you could also write
$$ \lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = - \infty$$
whatever you prefer I guess, both are perfectly readable in my opinion